How to get speedtest results from OpenSpeedTest using APIs?
I am trying to get results from a self hosted OpenSpeedTest server, but I am not able to find any APIs for the same.
I can see many API calls like: http://10.86.37.20:3000/download?n=0.015355377695134287, http://10.86.37.20:3000/download?n=0.6503051365529298 but they are not returning any response, just  starts a download of a 50 Mb file. Is there any way I can leverage these APIs to calculate the speed?
Currently I am using selenium to scrape the results when the speed test is over.
download = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'downResult').text
upload = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'upRestxt').text
ping = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pingResult').text
jitter = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'jitterDesk').text

Is there any way I can use the APIs or scrape the results using beautiful soup since selenium can't be used in the project I am assigned?

Maybe this will help you https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli

This speedtest-cli is for speedtest.net by Ookla, I am trying to use OpenSpeedTest which is an opensource tool.
